# Ubuntu as backup and file share

Tags: windows, automount, macosx, file-sharing, crashplan

I have a desktop with three internal drives.

- 80GB main drive with Ubuntu installed
- 1.5TB data drive formatted to NTFS
- 1.5TB data drive formatted to NTFS

What I want is for the two NTFS drives to be automatically mounted to the same point so Crashplan can see and backup from/to them. As it is now when the machine restarted it doesn't seem to recognize them and then when remounted the drive is treated as new and the entire backup starts all over again.

Additionally, I'd like to be able share the NTFS drives over my local network so my wife's Windows PC and my Mac can connect to them for read/write.

I know this information could probably be cobbled together from existing resources, but I have very little time to work on this issue (new baby) and want to be sure my data is safe; I'm very new to linux. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to give credit where credit is due. I was able to get this resolved with the help of these guides:

- [How to setup Samba shares to only be accessed by certain users?](https://askubuntu.com/a/208173/54624)
- [Did Mavericks Kill your Samba Access?](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/10/27/did-mavericks-kill-your-network-drive-access-heres-a-fix/)
- [How Do I correctly Mount an NTFS Partition with FSTAB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)

Answer (score 1):

If You like to learn a bit for Yourself, You are for sure able to do all the stuff by Your own.
Some tips:
get information about Your needs:

1. For mounting devices on boot look how to setup /etc/fstab file
2. For making them accessible under the same root directory get information about how to create links (hardlink or symbolic) depending on what You prefer
3. For sharing to Microsoft network You need to get information about samba and need to install it

Try Your best based on above hints. It would be a lot for me to write to explain "how to" and there is no garantee that what i write can be understood precicely being able to reach the goals.

If You need any help write to my e-mail josef.klotzner@gmail.com

cu